# Dynamically Replacing by a Function in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Is there a way to dynamically replace by a function, similar to how `.replace` works in JavaScript? A comparable use case would be I have a string with numbers and I would like to pass the numbers through a function:

```
"1 2 3" => "2 4 6"  (x2)
```

The current `preg_replace` function doesn't seem to support a function for the argument.

For reference, in JavaScript it can be implemented as the following:

```
var str = "1 2 3";
str.replace(/\d+/g, function(num){
    return +num * 2;
});
```

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) that has callback for regex matches. You can multiply matches digit in callback function.

```
$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/\d+/", function($matches){
    return $matches[0] * 2;
}, $str);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/IT00f)

Comment: Is there a way to get the index as well?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The function return matches part in array `$matches` and you can see all index of it using `print_r($matches)`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes, your code has two problem. First, you should set regex parameter of function between `//`. Second, you should increase value of `$i` before `return` because return break the function execution. See https://3v4l.org/2bYAh

Comment: Yea I realized the problems after a while... I think I really need a coffee right now. Anyway, thanks for the answer.